# how can I get the unit in last place(ULP) in PHP

Tags: php, math

in java there is `Math.ulp(123.456f)` I can't seem to find an equivalent in php.  I am looking for floating point precision not double.

Surprisingly there is a ton of bad advice on how to compare floats when looking for php answers. The most common one I see is

```
function floatCompare($a,$b) {
   return (abs($a-$b)<0.001);
}
```

this is a bad idea since what if your value is 0.000005.  A much better way to do this would be

```
function floatCompare($a,$b) {
   return (abs($a-$b)<ulp($a)*5);
}
```

but the ulp command does not exist in php.

Comment: yes always first thing I do.  I searched several different strings but can't find.

Comment: I don't see what the big deal is. Why not having a third argument if you need different precisions? Also, in PHP there's no real difference between float an double

Comment: You could look at the source for `Math.ulp(double d)` here: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Math-source.html and then translate it to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help.  I took Zéychin advice and cloned the ulp function from the java library.  I have started a Math library with this function.  Will add more over time.

https://github.com/OakbankTechnologyInc/Math

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Single precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) we see there are 23 bits in the mantissa of a float. 2^23 = 8,388,608. You can use this to test for a small difference

```
abs($a-$b) < abs($a)/8388608
```

This might be too sensitive, as it is just allowing for one bit of difference. Using 2^20= 1048576 will give a bit more leeway. The numbers will have to agree to 6 significant figures.